# Programmatically create an object then release it later

Tags: iphone, objective-c, release, retain

I programmatically create an ActivityIndicatorView with

```
UIActivityIndicatorView* cactivity = [[[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] 
 initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhite] retain];
```

Then when I want to stopAnimating and release in the next
`- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading`, im using an undeclared identifier? But i thought i retained it and had to release it myself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off there is no need to retain the `UIActivityIndicatorView` after you `alloc` `init` it, it already has an retain count of 1.

Just declare an `UIActivityIndicatorView` in the .h file, so you can then reference it as a Instance variable. (thnx Rob).

Comment: Instance variable, not class variable.

Comment: That was my original plan.. also the root of this problem. I just wanted to create it in the IB and connect it to some code, however i couldnt ctrl-drag it to the .h file, and couldnt connect the uiactivityindicator in .h to the .xib object, so I went programatically. I never encountered this before though, so I figured the programmatic way would be an easier solution.

Comment: You should be able to create an `IBOutlet` in the `.h` then use IB to connect that property.

Comment: Never mind, I recreated the class and the xib, and that worked. Did it the 'conventional' way by using the IB. thanks all!

Answer (score 1):

Undeclared identifier means the variable is not defined in the current scope. To have the same variable available in multiple methods, make it a class ivar or property.

Answer (score 1):

**Local Declaration** : You have declared the **UIActivityIndicator** in a local method due to which it is unreachable to other methods. You'll have to declare in the header file. Also, give it property of retain. Then, you can access it wherever you want.

**No need of Retain Message** : Also, when you have initialized it, its retain count is increased by 1, so no need to pass the retain message to it. You'll be having access to it anyways.

Answer (score 1):

Try to get to the result or avoid warnings using "autorelease". But this is not suppose to be good in every case.